# Printing resampled data into a text or csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, timestamp, text-files

I have 30 minute incremental data that I resampled to monthly average using Pandas.  How do I paste the resampled data into a text or csv file? Please see my script and sample data below.

```
import pandas as pd
data = r'C:\Creek\data\30Min_flow.csv'
flowdata=pd.read_csv(data,parse_dates='DateTime',index_col=0)
monthly=flowdata.resample('M',how='mean')
```

I would like to print the monthly variable into a text or csv file.  Below I have a sample of the data.

```
DateTime    F1_cfs  F2_cfs  F3_cfs  F4_cfs  F5_cfs  F6_cfs  F7_cfs
1/20/1992 9:30  0.23    0.34    0.34    0.8 1.01    2.24    1.4
1/20/1992 10:00 0.22    0.34    0.33    0.8 1.01    2.24    1.4
1/20/1992 10:30 0.22    0.34    0.33    0.8 1.01    2.24    1.4
1/20/1992 11:00 0.22    0.34    0.33    0.8 1.01    2.24    1.4
1/20/1992 11:30 0.21    0.34    0.33    0.8 1.01    2.24    1.4
1/20/1992 12:00 0.22    0.34    0.33    0.8 1.01    2.24    1.4
1/20/1992 12:30 0.22    0.34    0.33    0.8 1.01    2.24    1.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv):

```
monthly.to_csv(r'c:\Creek\data\monthly.csv')
```